# IncompatibleBlocktypes sending nsdictionary to the parameter

Tags: ios, return-value, objective-c-blocks, mbprogresshud

Showing an error like this some problem with the completion block return type.

```
 -(NSDictionary*)makeWebServiceCallAmmendments
{   
    __block NSDictionary*DicWebResponsePersonel;
    NSMutableDictionary *DictAppPatData=[PatientData sharedManager:nil];
    NSString*StrUrlContact=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@patient/getPatientDetails?pid=%@&type=ammendments",MainUrlUPDATEServer,[DictAppPatData objectForKey:@"pid"]];
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:StrUrlContact];
    MBProgressHUD *hud= [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:hud];
    hud.labelText = @"Please wait...";
    [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^(void)
     {
        DicWebResponsePersonel=[[SRUtility sharedManager]makeWebServicecallForGetmethod:url];         
     } completionBlock:^(void)
     {
         return DicWebResponsePersonel;
     }];
}
```

in completionBlock showing error like **incompatible block pointer types sending ‘nsdictionary’(^)(void)’to parameter of type ‘MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock’(aka ‘void(^)()’)**

Comment: Please share some code so other can give you answer.

Comment: Please provide details, we can not guess your issue. Code, stacktrace whatever helps understanding ...

Comment: Please share the code for the help?

Comment: Look at your post. Do you think anyone is willing to read it?

Comment: I am new in posting questions in stackoverflow sorry for the inconvinince.Now i think its in the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `completionBlock` return type is `void`. So `completionBlock` can't return any value.

```
typedef void (^MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)();
- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block completionBlock:(MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)completion;
```

- https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/d9886df3ad80faa5105b9e202e5302cf54c2bb43/MBProgressHUD.h#L88
- https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/d9886df3ad80faa5105b9e202e5302cf54c2bb43/MBProgressHUD.h#L249

Anyway, you want to make `makeWebServiceCallAmmendments` method returns `DicWebResponsePersonel`? It is not good idea.

According to MBProgressHUD header, `whileExecutingBlock` is executed on a background queue, and `completionBlock` is executed on completion of `whileExecutingBlock`.

```
/**
 * Shows the HUD while a block is executing on a background queue, then hides the HUD.
 *
 * @see showAnimated:whileExecutingBlock:onQueue:completionBlock:
 */
- (void)showAnimated:(BOOL)animated whileExecutingBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block completionBlock:(MBProgressHUDCompletionBlock)completion;

...

 * @param block The block to be executed while the HUD is shown.
 * @param completion The block to be executed on completion.
```

Your code would be executed like the following.

```
-(NSDictionary*)makeWebServiceCallAmmendments
{   

    /*
     * This method call is invoked on the main queue
     */

    ...

    [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^(void) {

        /*
         * This block is invoked on a background queue.
         * It will take long time.
         */ 

        DicWebResponsePersonel=[[SRUtility sharedManager]makeWebServicecallForGetmethod:url];         

     } completionBlock:^(void) {

        /*
         * This block is invoked on the main queue after the previous whileExecutingBlock finished
         */

         // return DicWebResponsePersonel;

     }];

     /*
      * Want to return DicWebResponsePersonel!
      * Have to wait the completionBlock finished!
      */
}
```

So, your `makeWebServiceCallAmmendments` method have to wait the completionBlock was invoked in order to return `DicWebResponsePersonel` value. But it also means block the main thread long time. Totally bad app. You should avoid this way.

Comment: i got the answer before itself.. anyways thanks Kazuki Sakamoto